# Ajax post not returning value from cakephp controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

```js
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/saveForm/" + user_id,
    datatype: 'json',
    data: "formname=" + formname + "&status=" + status,
    success: function (json)
    {
        alert("id is : " + json.forms[0].id);
    } //success
}); //ajax
```

The above code doesn't alerts me the id. why so....
My controller code is like

```js
function saveForm()
{
    //$userId=$this->Session->read('userId');
    $this - > data['Form']['name'] = $this - > params['form']['formname'];
    $this - > data['Form']['created_by'] = $this - > Session - > read('userId');
    $this - > data['Form']['status'] = $this - > params['form']['status'];
    $this - > data['Form']['access'] = "Private";
    $userId = $this - > Form - > saveForms($this - > data);
    $formid = $this - > Form - > find('all', array('fields' = > array('Form.id'),
        'order' = > 'Form.id DESC'));

    $this - > set('formid', $formid);
}
```

And my **save_form.ctp** has

```php
<?php
    $data = array();
?>

<?php
    foreach ($formid as $r):
        array_push($data, array(
            'id' => $r['Form']['id']
        ));
    endforeach;
    echo json_encode(array(
        "forms" => $data
    ));
?>
```

Comment: You might get further with this on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
print "<br />POST<br />";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   print $key . " " . $value . "<br />";
}


print "<br />GET<br />";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
   print $key . " " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

to see what comes in POST and GET array